# ComboBox Selected Item is working after edit the name in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am having one ComboBox inside my WPF application which is initially not allowed to edit and the selected item also set. So whenever I click on the Combobox, I will call a dropdownOpen event and make the Combobox in an editable mode based on some condition. After I rename the Combobox I called a KeyUp event on the Combobox and check for an Enter KeyPress, if the keypress is an Enter, I change the name of the item I edited. Till here, everything working perfectly except after editing the Text, I am not able to set the Selected Item. How I can set the Selected Item of Combobox after editing the name.

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="module" Padding="5 0 0 0" IsEditable="False" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" materialDesign:ComboBoxAssist.ClassicMode="True"  FontFamily="{StaticResource MontserratMedium}" Height="28.4" Background="#f1f1f1" BorderBrush="#f1f1f1" BorderThickness="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="368.56" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#525252" FontSize="14" DropDownOpened="module_DropDownOpened_1" SelectionChanged="module_SelectionChanged" KeyUp="module_KeyUp"/>
```

Code for KeyUp

```
 private void module_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter) return;

        // your event handler here
        e.Handled = true;
        string NewName = ((System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)sender).Text;
        var edtBx = sender as ComboBox;
        var activeModule = parentWindow.createApp.GetActiveModule();
        activeModule.GivenName = NewName;
        edtBx.SelectedItem = activeModule.GivenName;
        edtBx.IsEditable = false;
        first.Focus();
    }
```

Please let me know a way to set the SelectedItem back. Initially, It was there because I set in some other part of the code in same way(**edtBx.SelectedItem = activeModule.GivenName;**). The activeModule.givenName is giving the exact value I edited, but I am not able to set it as SelectedItem.

Comment: what is the type of ComboBox items? with your current code they must be string, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: the problem is that the item that you are trying to select does not exist in the combo box. You need to first add it to the combo box.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick way to select the item which you just edited, you should listen to SelectedItemChanged and store the last one in a local variable. as soon as the text changes, selected item is set to null.